# Removing boxes around radio buttons

Tags: css, radio-button, html5boilerplate

On Chrome (chromium), IE and Opera browsers, but not Firefox, I have long boxes that are unsightly (made much worse when hover shadow effects are utilised).

[image: checkboxes]

The code which produces this effect must occur more than once as it only disappears when I delete a couple of my css files.

There is no specific mention of type="radio" in my css files. The form that the radio buttons are attached to has its own class.

**To try and reset the css relating specifically to the radio buttons** I used

```
#resetter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

And then set the id of the radio buttons to "resetter", but no apparent change. If there is some way to remove this errant css affecting the radio buttons I would be delighted! (For the record I marked every line of the above with !important, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it didn't crop up in Firefox helped me solve the problem: it wasn't a border but a shadow.

Specifically:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(?, ?, ?, ?) ?px ?px ?px;
```

When substituted with:

```
-moz-box-shadow: ?px ?px ?px #?;
```

Compatibility was maintained with firefox, without resulting in ugly boxes on other browsers

Comment: -moz-box-shadow: none;